# Unrecognized character � when convert project to Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xtext

When I convert my xtext project to maven in eclipse, an recoginzed character (diomand question mark �) appread.

Before converting the project it was like this :
in the file `MyLangGenerator.xtend`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<Entities>
                «GetItem(entities)»
                «IF isValid»
                «GetFoo(entities)»
                «ENDIF»     
</Entities>
```

After converting to Maven it goes like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<Entities>
                �GetItem(entities)�
                �IF isValid�
                �GetFoo(entities)�
                �ENDIF�     
</Entities>
```

This my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.xtext.mypath</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.xtext.mypath</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <properties>
 
        <xtextVersion>2.27.0</xtextVersion>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <SdlFileName>myfilename</SdlFileName>
        
    

    </properties>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
              

    <resources>
       <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>

       <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtend</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtext</include>
                    <include>**/*.mwe2</include>
                    <include>**/*.tokens</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtextbin</include>
                </includes>
      </resource>
      
    
             <resource>
        <directory>src-gen</directory>

       <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtend</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtext</include>
                    <include>**/*.mwe2</include>
                    <include>**/*.tokens</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtextbin</include>
                </includes>
      </resource>
      
      
     
       <resource>
        <directory>xtend-gen</directory>

       <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtend</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtext</include>
                    <include>**/*.mwe2</include>
                    <include>**/*.tokens</include>
                    <include>**/*.xtextbin</include>
                </includes>
      </resource>


    
 
    
     
       <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
                    <includes>                      

                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>                      

      </resource>
    </resources>
    
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
            <id>add-gen-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
               <source>src-gen</source>
             
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>add-extra-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>xtend-gen</source>
               
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
  
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>org.xtext.mypath.generator.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
                     
                <finalName>${SdlFileName}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>


        </configuration>
              <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
          <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>

    </plugin>

     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
 
</plugin>
   


                        


     
                
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${xtextVersion}</version>
                 
                  

            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            exec-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.2.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>java</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0.v20100614-1136</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>

   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${xtextVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext</artifactId>
            <version>${xtextVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.xbase</artifactId>
            <version>${xtextVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator</artifactId>
            <version>${xtextVersion}</version>

        </dependency>
                    

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.0-jre</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>

    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>


 </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've tried to look up for this issue but no luck! I think it is something related to Unicode?

Comment: just because the file says `encoding='UTF-8'` does not mean that UTF-8 is actually used. The character � in Unicode is used in the wrong encoding. Which means that the actual original file is not in UTF-8.

Comment: @mrmcwolf I checked the resource tab in project properties and it says that the text file encoding used is UTF-8

Comment: Please post a link to the *actual* file. You might try ```&laquo;```  and ```&raquo;```

Comment: Before or after conversion? Actually, when you convert a project, it only changes the settings of the IDE, with those of the `pom.xml` file. The files themselves are not changed. If you get � it means there is a wrongly encoded character above 0x7f. Open the file in your local single byte code table and the problem should go away. AFTER that, it's a good idea to convert **all files from your project to utf-8**.

Comment: maybe your original files were ISO-8859-1 or the like

Comment: which encoding do the actual files have? (rightklick in eclipse on the file, before the conversion)

Comment: @mrmcwolf can you have a look at this please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74472278/maven-removes-dependencies-licenses-copyright-notice-when-generate-the-jar

Answer (score 1):

I've figure out what the issue is

Huge thanks for **mr mcwolf** and **Christian Dietrich** for their hints.

the issue is that the original project was written in Widows-1256 so when I convert to maven, it automatically works in UTF-8 environment. So, I had to encode my maven to windows-1256 in order to meet the source project Unicode.

following this [article](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html) , I've added the following to my Pom.xml

```
 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1256</project.build.sourceEncoding>.
 </properties>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>windows-1256</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: i propose you to transcode the files to utf-8 anyway

Comment: @ChristianDietrich can you have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74472278/maven-removes-dependencies-licenses-copyright-notice-when-generate-the-jar